# C# Type Inference fails with methods that contain default parameters

Tags: c#, type-inference

Say I have the following method:

```
static int MethodWithDefaultParameters(int a, int b=0, int c=1)
{
    return a + b + c;
}
```

And then I use this method in a LINQ query like so:

```
Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(MethodWithDefaultParameters);
```

This fails with:

> Error 1   The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Of course, I can work around this by inserting a lambda that forwards the function call like this:

```
Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(i => MethodWithDefaultParameters(i));
```

But my question is why does the type inference fail? As far as I can tell, it should not be ambiguous as there is only one variant of the function that satisfies the input variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two overloads for `Select()`. One that takes as the second parameter (i.e. the delegate) a `Func<TSource, TResult>`, and one that takes a `Func<TSource, int, TResult>`. I.e. a method signature with either one parameter or two.

Your method satisfies neither. Even with the default values, it still has three parameters. Default parameters are a *compile-time* construct and must be provided at the call site. They aren't filled in at run-time via a call to a delegate instance.

So, in fact, your work-around is one of the two reasonable ways to address the problem. The other would be to implement the default parameters differently (i.e. "old-school" :) ):

```
static int MethodWithDefaultParameters(int a)
{
    return MethodWithDefaultParameters(a, 0, 1);
}

static int MethodWithDefaultParameters(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}
```

Then you can use `MethodWithDefaultParameters` in your call to `Select()` directly, as the compiler will find the single-parameter overload that is compatible with one of the `Select()` overloads.

Comment: Aha, so as far as the type inference engine is concerned the signature for MethodWithDefaultParameters will always be with three arguments - i.e. it will never see a version with only one parameter. Thanks for the explanation!